# Can someone explain to me what (NSString *) means with Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

I just started with Objective-C and I would like to understand the meaning of the following lines of code as I see it everywhere in objective-c but I'm not quite getting it 100%:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
```

I understand that the above line is a instance method passing one argument, what I don't understand is (NSString *)name.

another example is:

```
-(NSString *)name;
```

or

```
person.height = (NSObject *)something;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
```

`(NSString *)` is simply the type of the argument - a string object, which is the NSString class in Cocoa. In Objective-C you're always dealing with object references (pointers), so the "*" indicates that the argument is a reference to an `NSString` object.

In this example:

```
person.height = (NSObject *)something;
```

something a little different is happening: `(NSObject *)` is again specifying a type, but this time it's a "type casting" operation -- what this means is to take the "something" object reference (which could be an `NSString`, `NSNumber`, or ...) and treat it as a reference to an `NSObject`.

---

update - 
When talking about Objective-C objects (as opposed to primitive types like int or float), everything's ultimately a pointer, so the cast operation means "take this pointer an `X` and treat it as if it's pointing to a `Y`". For example, if you have a container class (like `NSArray`) that holds generic `NSObject`s, but you know that the the objects are actually strings, you might say:

```
NSString *myString = (NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

which means "retrieve the first object from the array, treating it as a string".

The cast is not actually converting the value, it's just a way of saying to the compiler "hey, I know that I'm assigning an X to a Y here, so don't give me a warning about it".

Comment: Does casting operation mean change the value type? Meaning, if is expecting an int, it changes to a bool, is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
```

Is a signature of a method that takes one parameter called `name` which is a pointer to `NSString`.

```
-(NSString *)name;
```

Is an accessor method called `name` that returns pointer to `NSString`.

```
person.height = (NSObject *)something;
```

Typecasts `something` to a `NSObject` pointer and then it is assigned to `person.height` property.

See more explanation in [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
    -----------------------------------------
    '-'  means its an instance method (+ is used for static methods)
    '(id)' is the return type    
    'initWithName' is the function name, the name implies its a constructor
    ':' start of parameter
    '(NSString*)' parameter type
    'name' parameter name
```

its the equivalent of

```
(id)initWithName( NSString* name )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(NSString *)name
```

is saying that a variable `name` is a pointer `*` to a NSString object. Its a pointer because the `name` variable isn't the string but rather it is just the address in memory for that string.

Comment: Does this means that I can access all the methods and properties of the NSString class? Lets suppose that NSString class has a method named doSomething, can then do [name doSomething]?

Comment: Just to make sure. So if I have -(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name; then inside initWithName method I can do [name soSomething]?

Comment: Yes and not just if the parameter is `(NSString *)name`, it could be any object type `(NSObject *)name`, `(MyObjPerson *)person`.